# script to design a command

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a command which gives me dates in specific patter but i want to redesign it.

```
$ for i in {21..27}; do    date +%Y%m%d --date="+${i} days ${start}"; done| sed
-e "s/^/*/g"|sed "s/$/*/g"
*20130822*
*20130823*
*20130824*
*20130825*
*20130826*
*20130827*
*20130828*
```

by this it prints dates in different rows i want output command to look like below by taking all dates in a row separated by spaces.

```
cp -av /cygdrive/w/*20130822 /cygdrive/w/*20130823 /cygdrive/w/*20130824 /cygdrive/w/*20130825 /cygdrive/w/*20130826 /cygdrive/w/*20130827 /cygdrive/w/*20130828 /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/;
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ start="08/01/2013"
$ for i in {21..27}; do    date +%Y%m%d --date="+${i} days ${start}"; done|
awk 'BEGIN{printf "cp -av"} {printf " /cygdrive/w/*%s",$0} END{print " /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/;"}'
cp -av /cygdrive/w/*20130822 /cygdrive/w/*20130823 /cygdrive/w/*20130824 /cygdrive/w/*20130825 /cygdrive/w/*20130826 /cygdrive/w/*20130827 /cygdrive/w/*20130828 /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/;
```

If you want to just generate the list of files an run cp on them:

```
$ start="08/01/2013"
$ cp -av $(for i in {21..27}; do    date +%Y%m%d --date="+${i} days ${start}"; done|
awk '{printf " /cygdrive/w/*%s",$0}') /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash (e.g. `bash script.sh 20130821`):

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$1

patterns=()
for i {0..6}; do
    patterns[${#patterns[@]}]="/cygdrive/w/*$(exec date '+%Y%m%d' --date="+${i} days ${start}")*"
done

cp -av ${patterns[*]} /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/
```

POSIX (e.g. `sh script.sh 20130821`):

```
#!/bin/sh

start=$1

patterns=''
for i in $(seq 0 6); do
    patterns="$patterns /cygdrive/w/*$(exec date '+%Y%m%d' --date="+${i} days ${start}")*"
done

cp -av $patterns /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/
```

Note: If you mean `/cygdrive/w/*yyyymmdd` (no `*` at the end), remove the last `*` in the pattern assignment.

You can also just save the script to `/usr/local/bin` e.g. `/usr/local/bin/myscript`. Change the execution permissions to `0755` or `0700` with `chmod` then you can ust run `myscript (date)`.

Comment: looks you got it perfectly, just suggest me how can i add /cygdrive/w/ in starting of each date.

Comment: @user2043380 I made the update. I added `/cygdrive/w/` on the assignment.

Comment: can you suggest the same in pattern of awk / shell script ?

Comment: @user2043380 Updated both for `bash` and posix `sh`.

Comment: $ /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/./test.sh
/cygdrive/c/KPI/test/./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{21.
.27}'
'cygdrive/c/KPI/test/./test.sh: line 3: `for i {21..27}; do

Comment: @user2043380 The former script could only run with bash so you have to run it with `bash script.sh`. The latter one is compatible with any POSIX like shell and could be ran with `sh script.sh`.

Comment: also be noted that here dates are part of file names, all i want is to give a start date and it should automatically take next 7 days date too here i was giving as 22aug to 28aug
Any idea how to do it and also check the error that i got while running your command

Comment: @user2043380 Please tell me first how it goes with the current scripts. I'll try to update. Also, please check if what you're running is really the right one. There might have been an update after you copy.

Comment: @user2043380 Updated to your requirement. You just have to start the loop from 0 to 6.

Comment: here is the scenario:- there are n number of files, and i want to search and copy specific files where file name contains date in it so all i want that i run the script by giving a value say 20130821 and then it automatically searches files with name *20130821* ..... *20130827* and copies them to target directory.

Comment: I run you last script but its taking dates as 20130908 to 20130914 while i want it to ask me for date like what if i want to copy files from 20130829 to 20130904 ?
any suggestions ?

Comment: made some changes to your command now its taking start date as 29 but all dates as 29 aug :( /////////////

#!/bin/bash

start=$1
patterns=''
for i in $(seq 0 6); do
    patterns="$patterns /cygdrive/w/*$(exec date '+%Y%m%d' --date="-10 days ${start}")*"
done

cp -av $patterns /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37014/discussion-between-user2043380-and-konsolebox)

Comment: @user2043380 I'm sorry but I believe your query has gone far already from your original question. Other conditions like making the script smart enough to think that the user might are already consider different dates is a different matter. I'm also not sure how it would be helpful to add a constant value `-10`. It seems like you never wanted this to be solved.

Comment: I am sorry to draw this confusion line.  
I have found a way to get d output in an automated way where I only need to crontab my script, all i have to do is use (-14 -7) in place of (0 6).

Comment: @user2043380 Please ask a specific goal next time please. This is not like a forum. And you should at least be grateful for any information one user could give you, especially if the one you're using now is generally based from their concept and code.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
export start=20130909
seq -s\  -f'/cygdrive/w/*$(date +%%Y%%m%%d -d"+%g days $start")' 21 27 |
sed 's|.*|echo "cp -av & /cygdrive/c/KPI/test"/|e'
```

This exports the `start` date (to enable later piped commands access to it). Produces the required sequence of numbers. Then substitutes the sequence into the required path. Finally the `cp` and final path commands are added then the entire string is passed to echo and evaluated.